# Ajax as a function with different success actions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have dozens of ajax calls on various pages and I am trying to consolidate code.  I have done as much so far by turning:

```
 $('#doAction1').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:data,
                    url:"someUrl.php",
                    success:function(result){
                            $('#results').html(result);
                    }
            });
 });
 $('#doAction2').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:data,
                    url:"someUrl.php",
                    success:function(result){
                            $('#results').html(result);
                            $('#results').addClass('happy');
                    }
            });
 });
 $('#doAction3').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:data,
                    url:"someUrl.php",
                    success:function(result){
                            alert('you clicked 3');
                    }
            });
 });
 $('#doAction4').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:data,
                    url:"someUrl.php",
                    success:function(result){
                            $('#error').html(result);
                            errorCounter++;
                            alert('There was an error');
                    }
            });
 });




<input type='button' id='doAaction1' class='someClass'>
<input type='button' id='doAaction2' class='someClass'>
<input type='button' id='doAaction3' class='someClass'>
<input type='button' id='doAaction4' class='someClass'>
```

into:

```
 function ajax(url,data,id){
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:data,
            url:url,
            success:function(result){
                    //various actions
            }
    });
  }


 $('.someClass').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      data = "Data";  
      //pass some other var for different success actions
      ajax('someUrl.php',data,id);

 });
```

My question is, how can i design this so that my success return is different?

for example, maybe on 1 call i do want to put the result into some selector, but what if on another one, I want to add some css to the selector as well, or do more than 1 thing in the success?

Comment: You want to pass a callback.  At which point your function is mostly useless.

Comment: so the consolidation of code is futile for this type of thing?

Comment: What code are you consolidating? You're saying that every single line of your function should be an input.

Comment: let me add some detail to original quesiton

Comment: It's not futile in general, however in this case your code is a wrapper for jQuery's wrapper of XMLHttpRequest. All you're doing is turning the three properties of the settings object in to parameters.

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything in common.

Comment: While not necessarily clean or best practice, you could pass an extra parameter and then put a switch/case inside your success function.

Comment: @SLaks The only difference between each of these ajax calls is the success actions.

Comment: @MCMXCII  what would be the best practices for this.  If the answer is 4 seperate click functions, im fine with that. just trying to write better code and I dont know the "standards" or best practices.

Comment: As they are four separate functions that do four separate jobs, it would probably be considered best practice to leave them separate, however in the interest of reducing repetition and therefore file size, you'd probably be better off consolidating it all into one function and then just passing an extra parameter into a switch/class in the success function, considering the only thing that does actually change is the success function.

Comment: Great thanks for the input